# How to Iterate a list of characters and compare different elements

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of strings which I would like to process, so lets say

```
val List<String?> = listOf("Q", NULL, "W", "E", NULL, "E", "E", "R", "R", "T") [sic]
```

I want to process this so that I can apply a predicate where there are two matching strings in adjacent positions and return a list of non nullable strings.

The method signature of the extension would then be

```
fun <T : Any> List<T?>.processList(action: (T) -> T): List<T>
```

lets say my predicate this time is to add "gotcha" to the first string in a duplicate and remove the second so in this case I would end up with

```
ListOf("Q", "W", "Egotcha", "E", "Rgotcha", "T")
```

I can do this in an old school way with a while loop very easily

a messy version being along these lines

```
val nL : ArrayList<T> = ArrayList<T>()
var indexThis : Int = 0
while ( indexThis < intermediate.size-1 ) {
    if (intermediate[indexThis] != intermediate[indexThis + 1]) {
        nL.add(intermediate[indexThis]!!)
        indexThis += 1 }
    else {
        nL.add(processList(intermediate[indexThis]!!))
        indexThis += 2 }
}
```

This is a long way from being the finished article but but was my attempt at getting the process clear in my head...

but I'm struggling to get started doing it in a more functional way

so I can see that I might want to do start with

```
 this.filter {a -> a != null}
```

but then I can't see where I would go as a next step ?  Then only method I can think of is forEachIndexed but my attempts at this this seem very convoluted I'm sure I've seen examples of people comparing items in a List in a map ?

and my last train of thought was going along the lines of

```
.map{b -> b?.run{b ...  processList (b)}}
```

but this seems very wrong

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first pass at this, which is a bit harder functionally because some state must be maintained as you accumulate the result.

```
fun <T> List<T?>.processList(action: (T) -> T): List<T> where T: Comparable<T> {
    data class Accumulator(val resultList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf(), var previousWasDupe: Boolean = false)

    return this.asSequence()
               .filterNotNull()
               .windowed(2, partialWindows = true).fold(Accumulator()) { accum, value ->
        if (accum.previousWasDupe) {
            // skip this one that was already consumed in the dupe
            accum.previousWasDupe = false
        } else if (value.size < 2 || value[0] != value[1]) {
            accum.resultList.add(value[0])
            accum.previousWasDupe = false  //  already is false, you could delete this line, here for clarity
        } else {
            accum.resultList.add(action(value[0]))
            accum.previousWasDupe = true
        }
        accum
    }.resultList

}
```

for your test case:

```
val items = listOf("Q", null, "W", "E", null, "E", "E", "R", "R", "T")
println(items.processList { it + "gotcha" })

// prints "[Q, W, Egotcha, E, Rgotcha, T]"
```

You could use am immutable accumulator as well (*I don't like it being mutable but it will perform better*), but there is no point in taking that hit given the state is internal to the function.  Whether this performs better as a sequence (as written) or with copies depends on the size of the lists and is hard to say without performance testing.

Notice that I also made sure the items `<T>` were `Comparable` so that we can be sure that `==` is doing what we expect, otherwise you really don't know you are receiving things that this function would even work upon.

---

For fun, the immutable version:

```
fun <T> List<T?>.processListImmutable(action: (T) -> T): List<T> where T: Comparable<T> {
    data class Accumulator(val resultList: List<T> = emptyList(), val previousWasDupe: Boolean = false)

    return this.asSequence()
        .filterNotNull()
        .windowed(2, partialWindows = true).fold(Accumulator()) { accum, value ->
            if (accum.previousWasDupe) {
                Accumulator(accum.resultList, false) // could also be: accum.copy(previousWasDupe = false)
            } else if (value.size < 2 || value[0] != value[1]) {
                Accumulator(accum.resultList + value[0], false)
            } else {
                Accumulator(accum.resultList + action(value[0]), true)
            }
        }.resultList
}
```

---

An edge case to check with solutions is the input:

```
val items = listOf("Q", null, "W", "E", null, 
                   "E", "E", "R", "R", "T", 
                   "Z", "Z", "Zgotcha")  // <--- this is the trap
```

which should return:

```
[Q, W, Egotcha, E, Rgotcha, T, Zgotcha, Zgotcha]
```

and not:

```
[Q, W, Egotcha, E, Rgotcha, T, Zgotchagotcha]
```

Comment: Thanks Jayson.  Pretty impressive, I hadn't realised it was so involved, I thought I was just being a bit slow...   I'm not sure about the edge case tbh, I was thinking about it, it's for an online course and sometimes you only find out the finer points of the requirement when you get the feedback (I'm not sure whether it is recursive so that Z, Z, Zgotcha should become  Zgotcha, Zgotcha or Zgotchagotcha !  This is more than enough for me to take the next steps myself though!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try next code:

```
fun List<String?>.processList(action: (String) -> String): List<String> {
    var remove = false
    val dest = arrayListOf<String>()
    return filterNotNullTo(dest).mapIndexedNotNull { index, s ->
        if (remove) {
            remove = false
            null
        } else {
            if (index + 1 <= dest.lastIndex && s == dest[index + 1]) {
                remove = true
                action()
            } else {
                s
            }
        }
    }
}

val l = listOf("Q", null, "W", "E", null, "E", "E", "R", "R", "T")
val result = l.processList {"${it}gotcha"}
```

Comment: This has a bug, in a case such as:
`val l = listOf("Z", "Z", "Zgotcha")`  You cannot use the last modified value as the source of duplicate comparison.  It would return `["Zgotchagotcha"]` instead of `["Zgotcha", "Zgotcha"]`

Comment: Also you should incorporate the action lambda in the function.

Comment: Edited my answer including the edge case

Comment: Your fix now introduces another edge case.  `val l = listOf("Z", "Z", "Zgotcha", "Zgotcha")` now does not return `["Zgotcha", "Zgotchagotcha"]` as it should.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like a fair answer to me but I think of the 2 Jayson's is a better proposition.

Comment: I edited my answer. Seems it works for that test cases